# How can I instruct Apache to apply different URL rewriting rules based on a query variable in the requested URL?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a set of rules in a `.htaccess` file that redirects all requests to `index.php`, but this is interfering with AJAX requests that need to access the requested file directly.

I am trying to resolve this by appending `?ajax=true` to all AJAX request URLs, and creating a rule that says "all URLs ending in `?ajax=true` should be processed directly".

Here is my `.htaccess` file currently:

```
RewriteEngine On      
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^ajax=true$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

My AJAX request URL would be as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/process_ajax.php?ajax=true
```

No luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are close with using a negative `RewriteCond` but the syntax could be a bit off. Try using parentheses like in my example below.

At first, I would use a wildcard value for the `GET` parameter like `.*` so you can focus on targeting the correct key. Once it's working you can test again for getting the right value, presumably `true`.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On      
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(ajax=.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC]
```